# Is there a way to know through inheritance (or other way) when a class defines the .map function in Scala?

Tags: scala

My problem is phrased in the code below.
I'm trying to get some input that has the .map function in it. I know that if I call .map to it, it will return an Int to me.

```
  // In my case, they are different representations of Ints
  // By that I mean that in the end it all boils down to Int
  val list: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3,4)
  val optInt: Option[Int] = Some(1)
  // I can use a .map with a Seq, check!
  list.map {
    value => println(value)
  }
  // I can use it with an Option, check!
  optInt.map {
    value => println(value)
  }
  // Well, you're asking yourself why do I have to do it,
  // Why don't I use foreach to solve my problem. Check!
  list.foreach(println)
  optInt.foreach(println)

  // The problem is that I don't know what I'm going to get as input
  // The only thing I know is that it's "mappable" (it has the .map function)
  // And that if I were to apply .map it would return Ints to me
  // Like this:
  def printValues(genericInputThatHasMap: ???) {
    genericInputThatHasMap.map {
      value => println(value)
    }
  }

  // The point is, what do I have to do to have this functionality?
  // I'm researching right now, but I still haven't found anything.
  // That's why I'm asking it here =(

  // this works:
  def printValues(genericInputThatHasMap: Seq[Int]) {
    genericInputThatHasMap.map {
      value => println(value)
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: @Luigi Thanks, I've read about that before but I haven't thought it would solve my problem, I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First for a quick note about `map` and `foreach`. If you're only interested in performing an operation with a side effect (e.g., printing to standard output or a file, etc.) on each item in your collection, use `foreach`. If you're interested in creating a new collection by transforming each element in your old one, use `map`. When you write `xs.map(println)`, you will in fact print all the elements of the collection, but you'll also get back a (completely useless) collection of units, and will also potentially confuse future readers of your code—including yourself—who expect `foreach` to be used in a situation like this.

Now on to your problem. You've run into what is in my opinion one of the ugliest warts of the Scala standard library—the fact that methods named `map` and `foreach` (and `flatMap`) get magical treatment at the language level that has nothing to do with a specific type that defines them. For example, I can write this:

```
case class Foo(n: Int) {
  def foreach(f: Int => Unit) {
    (0 until n) foreach f
  }
}
```

And use it in a `for` loop like this, simply because I've named my method `foreach`:

```
for (i <- Foo(10)) println(i)
```

You can use [structural types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#structural_types) to do something similar in your own code:

```
def printValues(xs: { def foreach(f: (Int) => Unit): Unit }) {
  xs foreach println
}
```

Here any `xs` with an appropriately typed `foreach` method—for example an `Option[Int]` or a `List[Int]`—will compile and work as expected.

Structural types get a lot messier when you're trying to work with `map` or `flatMap` though, and are unsatisfying in other ways—they impose some ugly overhead due to their use of runtime reflection, for example. They actually have to be [explicitly enabled in Scala 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338908/334519) to avoid warnings for these reasons.

As senia's answer points out, the [Scalaz library](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) provides a much more coherent approach to the problem through the use of [*type classes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) like `Monad`. You wouldn't want to use `Monad`, though, in a case like this: it's a much more powerful abstraction than you need. You'd use `Each` to provide `foreach`, and `Functor` for `map`. For example, in Scalaz 7:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def printValues[F[_]: Each](xs: F[Int]) = xs foreach println
```

Or:

```
def incremented[F[_]: Functor](xs: F[Int]) = xs map (_ + 1)
```

To summarize, you can do what you want in a standard, idiomatic, but arguably ugly way with structural types, or you can use Scalaz to get a cleaner solution, but at the cost of a new dependency.

Comment: Thanks! My example is a rather contrived one. I'm developing a lib to aid me in a play project and I thought that copying and paste my problem here would just add boilerplate to the matter. I'm going to study senia's and your answer now.

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts on the two approaches.

### Structural Types

You can use a structural type for `foreach`, but for `map` it doesn't appear you can construct one to work across multiple types.  For example:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

object StructuralMap extends App {
  type HasMapAndForeach[A] = {
//    def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
    def foreach[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Unit
  }

  def printValues(xs: HasMapAndForeach[Any]) {
    xs.foreach(println _)
  }

//  def mapValues(xs: HasMapAndForeach[Any]) {
//    xs.map(_.toString).foreach(println _)
//  }

  def forComp1(xs: HasMapAndForeach[Any]) {
    for (i <- Seq(1,2,3)) println(i)
  }

  printValues(List(1,2,3))

  printValues(Some(1))

  printValues(Seq(1,2,3))

//  mapValues(List(1,2,3))
}

scala> StructuralMap.main(new Array[String](0))
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

See the `map` method commented out above, it has `List` hardcoded as a type parameter in the `CanBuildFrom` implicit.  There might be a way to pick up the type generically - I will leave that as a question to the Scala type gurus out there.   I tried substituting `HasMapAndForeach` and `this.type` for `List` but neither of those worked.

The usual performance caveats about structural types apply.

### Scalaz

Since structural types is a dead end if you want to support `map` then let's look at the scalaz approach from Travis and see how it works.  Here are his methods:

```
def printValues[F[_]: Each](xs: F[Int]) = xs foreach println

def incremented[F[_]: Functor](xs: F[Int]) = xs map (_ + 1)
```

(In the below correct me if I am wrong, I am using this as a scalaz learning experience)

The typeclasses `Each` and `Functor` are used to restrict the types of `F` to ones where implicits are available for `Each[F]` or `Functor[F]`, respectively.   For example, in the call

```
printValues(List(1,2,3))
```

the compiler will look for an implicit that satisfies `Each[List]`.  The `Each` trait is

```
trait Each[-E[_]] {
  def each[A](e: E[A], f: A => Unit): Unit
}
```

In the `Each` object there is an implicit for `Each[TraversableOnce]` (`List` is a subtype of `TraversableOnce` and the trait is contravariant):

```
object Each {
  implicit def TraversableOnceEach[A]: Each[TraversableOnce] = new Each[TraversableOnce] {
    def each[A](e: TraversableOnce[A], f: A => Unit) = e foreach  f
  }
}
```

Note that the "context bound" syntax

```
def printValues[F[_]: Each](xs: F[Int])
```

is shorthand for

```
def printValues(xs: F[Int])(implicit ev: Each[F])
```

Both of these denote that `F` is a member of the `Each` typeclass.  The implicit that satisfies the typeclass is passed as the `ev` parameter to the `printValues` method.

Inside the `printValues` or `incremented` methods the compiler doesn't know that `xs` has a `map` or `foreach` method because the type parameter `F` doesn't have any upper or lower bounds. As far as it can tell `F` is `AnyRef` and satisfies the context bound (is part of the typeclass).   What is in scope that does have `foreach` or `map`?  `MA` from scalaz has both `foreach` and `map` methods:

```
trait MA[M[_], A] {
  def foreach(f: A => Unit)(implicit e: Each[M]): Unit = e.each(value, f)

  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit t: Functor[M]): M[B] = t.fmap(value, f)
}
```

Note that the `foreach` and `map` methods on `MA` are constrained by the `Each` or `Functor` typeclass.   These are the same constraints from the original methods so the constraints are satisfied and an implicit conversion to `MA[F, Int]` takes place via the `maImplicit` method:

```
trait MAsLow extends MABLow {
  implicit def maImplicit[M[_], A](a: M[A]): MA[M, A] = new MA[M, A] {
    val value = a
  }
}
```

The type `F` in the original method becomes type `M` in `MA`.

The implicit parameter that was passed into the original call is then passed as the implicit parameter into `foreach` or `map`.  In the case of `foreach`, `each` is called on its implicit parameter `e`.  In the example from above the implicit `ev` was type `Each[TraversableOnce]` because the original parameter was a `List`, so `e` is the same type.  `foreach` calls `each` on `e` which delegates to `foreach` on `TraversableOnce`.

So the order of calls for `printValues(List(1,2,3))` is:

`new Each[TraversableOnce]` -> `printValues` -> `new MA` -> `MA.foreach` -> `Each.each` -> `TraversableOnce.foreach`

As they say, there is no problem that can't be solved with an extra level of indirection :)

Answer (score 2):

You can [use `MA`](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/MA.scala.html) from [`scalaz`](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def printValues[A, M[_]](ma: MA[M, A])(implicit e: Each[M]) {
  ma |>| { println _ }
}

scala> printValues(List(1, 2, 3))
1
2
3

scala> printValues(Some(1))
1
```